# React-Native problems with AVD

Tags: react-native, expo

anyone know how to correct "new updates available, downloading..." kinda issues?
it works fine in web browser but  doesn't work on my android phone and any of the AVDs of android studio.
it's been a week and i can't figure out the problem.

[side by side view of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlowd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears somehow i updated my mac os to the new version, macos 12 beta.... they have so many issues since the release, i tried my project on mac 11 and it's working fine. thank you so much @Slbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `app.json` file:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
  }
}
```

`fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0` will disable the wait for downloading, and instead the update will be downloaded silently and the app will be updated on the next run.

Comment: it's included in app.json file but it's still the same response. these are the things i tried:
1. cold boot, wipe data and rerun after rebooting my mac.
2. upgrade android studio, update react-native packages and even tried sdk43

Comment: Does it occur with a new project? I've never hit anything like that, although I've certainly hit some weird quirks with Expo.

Comment: Yes it occurs in a brand new react-native project, i have been trying so many things and it keeps on saying "new updates available, downloading..." i almost gave up and looking for alternative solution to use instead of expo-cli.

Comment: Are you [manually invoking](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9386) the `Updates` module? If so, maybe try letting it work automatically instead? Otherwise I'd try cleaning your yarn/npm caches, uninstalling Node entirely, and then reinstalling everything. Note that the `Updates` module [doesn't work for the web](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/), which is probably why you're not having any problem there.